How to Preview and Validate Street View Publish API Photo Connections Before Publishing to Google Business Profile?
I have successfully connected multiple photospheres using the Google Street View Publish API. The photospheres are linked with proper metadata, including latitude, longitude, heading, and connections between the images.
Before publishing these photospheres publicly or associating them with a Google Business Profile, I want to preview how the navigation and transitions between the photospheres will work—essentially simulating how the Street View experience will look to users.
Is there a way to test or preview the connected photospheres in real time (e.g., a sandbox or private mode) before they go live on Google Maps or the Business Profile? I’d like to ensure all connections and coordinates are correct without waiting for Google’s 24-48 hour processing window.
Any guidance on testing tools, workflows, or API features to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
